# Sizing a wx.TextCtrl widget?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm in the process of learning to use wxWidgets and Python, but I'm having some trouble figuring out how to size widgets within a frame.

I am under the impression that I can set the size of various widgets by giving them a custom size=(x,y) value when calling the constructor. This code is copied and pasted out of the examples for wxPython and I have added the value="example",pos=(0,0) and size=(100,100) values to the wx.TextCtrl() constructor, but when I run this program, the text control takes up the entirety of the 500x500 frame. I'm not sure why, and I'd appreciate any help you could give me to get it to work.

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500,500))
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,value="example",pos=(0,0),size=(100,100))
        self.CreateStatusBar() # A Statusbar in the bottom of the window

        # Setting up the menu.
        filemenu= wx.Menu()

        # wx.ID_ABOUT and wx.ID_EXIT are standard IDs provided by wxWidgets.
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About"," Information about this program")
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"E&xit"," Terminate the program")

        # Creating the menubar.
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu,"&File") # Adding the "filemenu" to the MenuBar
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "Sample editor")
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Please read the [sizers overview](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_sizer.html) in the manual to know about how to size widgets correctly.

As for your particular example, it's an exception due to the fact that `wxFrame` always resizes its only window to fill its entire client area -- just because this is what you almost always want. However typically this only window is a `wxPanel` which, in turn, contains other controls and uses sizers to position them.

**TL;DR**: You should never use absolute positioning, i.e. specifying positions in pixels.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the comment you should never use absolute positioning

Comment: Using absolute positioning was a very bad idea even in 2013 (or 2003), but it's a horrible one in 2018 due to the spread of high DPI screens.

Answer (score 1):

For sure you need to read from this book: [wxPython 2.8 Application Development Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/wxpython-2-8-application-development-cookbook/book)

> Read -> *Chapter 7: Window Layout and Design*

---

In your code, add widgets holder: panel.

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500,500))

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(panel,-1,value="example",pos=(0,0),size=(100,100))
        self.CreateStatusBar() # A Statusbar in the bottom of the window

        # Setting up the menu.
        filemenu= wx.Menu()

        # wx.ID_ABOUT and wx.ID_EXIT are standard IDs provided by wxWidgets.
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About"," Information about this program")
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"E&xit"," Terminate the program")

        # Creating the menubar.
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu,"&File") # Adding the "filemenu" to the MenuBar
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "Sample editor")
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]